# Какой знак поставить в скобках?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

*Перед вами простирается великолепной красоты город () Москва.*
То есть вопрос состоит в том, что считать приложением: *великолепной красоты город* или *Москва*?
Как отличить определяемое слово от приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно учитывать, что приложения обозначают:

> - профессию лица, его звание, должность, социальное положение, род занятий, возраст, родственные отношения пол и т. п. (француз-учитель,
>     писатель-романист, профессор Циммерман, девушка-крестьянка,
>     отец-старик, девочка-школьница, старик дворник, осетин-извозчик);
> - качества, свойства предмета, образную характеристику лиц и предметов (приложения-эпитеты) (девочка-умница, завод-гигант, красавец мужчина,
>     утес-великан, судьба-злодейка, проказница-зима);
> - свойства или качества живых существ (соловей-певун, петух-драчун, чайки-рыболовы);
> - назначение предмета (вагон-ловушка),
> - **географические названия (река Дон,** порт Таганрог, город Ижевск, пустыня Сахара);
> - названия растений, птиц, зверей и т. д. (дерево кипарис, заяц русак, цветок лилия);
> - условные названия предметов (магазин "Оптика", журнал "Наука и техника", фильм "Ночной дозор");
> - прозвища (Владимир Красное Солнышко, Ричард Львиное Сердце);
> - клички животных и людей (медведь Муха, собака Дружок, гражданин по прозванью Каланча).
>
> Для разграничения определяемого слова и приложения следует учитывать
>   следующие признаки:
>
> - если одно из существительных является подлежащим, то сказуемое согласуется с ним, а не с приложением: Журнал «Итоги» уже продан. —
>     Журнал продан; Девушка-почтальон разносила газеты. — Девушка
>     разносила;
> - если при склонении одно из слов сохраняет форму именительного падежа, то это приложение: журнал «Итоги», в журнале «Итоги»;
> - в необособленных приложениях при сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени неодушевлённых предметов **приложением является имя
>     собственное**: река Волга, журнал «Итоги»;
> - при сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени (фамилии) человека приложением является имя нарицательное: директор Ушаков, брат Иван;
> - при сочетании нарицательных и собственных имен возможны варианты, поэтому в данном случае следует учитывать значение имен
>     существительных (приложение обычно указывает на качество, свойство,
>     национальность, возраст, профессию, социальное положение, родственные
>     связи предмета).
>
> По мере развития языка определяемое слово и приложение нередко
>   сливаются в цельное сочетание — один член предложения (княжна Марья,
>   товарищ капитан, капитан Иванов, Волга-матушка, Иван-царевич,
>   Аника-воин, матушка-Земля, матушка-Русь), а иногда и в одно слово
>   (диван-кровать, платье-костюм, хлеб-соль).

https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/213-prilogenie.html

**Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений может использоваться тире в следующих случаях**:

1) **если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить а именно** (особенно если приложение стоит в конце предложения, имеет зависимые слова и внутри него уже есть знаки препинания).

В дальнем углу светилось желтое пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни (М. Горький);

2) **если одиночное или распространённое приложение стоит в конце предложения и при этом подчеркивается его самостоятельность или даётся разъяснение такого приложения.**
Я не слишком люблю это дерево – осину (Тургенев); В углу гостиной стояло пузатое бюро на пренелепых четырёх ногах – совершенный медведь (Гоголь);

3) если приложение стоит в середине предложения и имеет пояснительный характер (тире ставится с двух сторон).
Какая-то ненатуральная зелень – творение скучных беспрерывных дождей – покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (Гоголь).

Примечание. Второе тире опускается:

а) если после обособленного приложения ставится запятая, например: Используя специальное устройство – шагометр, я рассчитал оптимальную нагрузку для своего организма (Васильев);

б) если приложение выражает более конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово – более общее значение, например: На совещании министров иностранных дел – членов «большой восьмёрки» выступил министр иностранных дел России;

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html

У нас **географическое название, одиночное  приложение стоит в конце предложения** и при этом подчеркивается его самостоятельность, к тому же перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить **а именно**, следовательно, ставим **тире**:

*Перед вами простирается великолепной красоты город - Москва.*